# Springboot/Tomcat and configuring threadpool question

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am working with a springboot application in which we are consistently scaling up and down to match demand. I have noticed that my p99 latencies seem to be much higher when a new server comes online.

I have and endpoint that declares the application is ready when it comes online, so this means that the node shouldn't accept connections until the application is running. I also am establishing connections for databases before the application is ready so I can reduce this warmup latency.

Does anyone know how Tomcat is configured within springboot with regards to thread pools? Will it create new threads on demand? Is there a way to have tomcat create these threads upon startup? Any other thoughts to troubleshoot this initial latency hit?

TIA

Comment: Tomcat already has a pool of 200 threads at startup.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did a thread dump of a running springboot app, and I didn't see 200 threads.

Comment: They are in a tomcat threadpool, so unless you configured it otherwise they should be there.

Comment: They must be created the threads as needed, because I can see the following metric:  `jvm_threads_peak_threads 111.0`

Comment: @M.Deinum: looks like this might be the answer: `server.tomcat.min-spare-threads` – The minimum number of threads always kept running. This includes both active and idle threads.

Comment: At leat there are threads, so 200 is the max probably (or something changed in tomcat versions which could also be the case).